# How to detect text in a photo

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I am researching into the best way to detect test in a photo using open source libraries.

I think the standard way is as follows (note: steps 1 - 4 all use OpenCV):

1) detect outline of document

2) transform document so it's flat and cropped, using said outline

3) Make the background of document white, using a filter

4) Feed resulting image to Tesseract

Is this the optimum process, or is there a better way, or better tools? 
Also, what happens for case if the photo doesn't have a document outline (It's possible that step 1 & 2 are redundant)?

Is there anyway to automatically detect document orientation (i.e. portrait / landscape)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your process is fine. I've used a similar process for an Android project.
I think that the only way you can discover if a document is portrait/landscape is to reason with the length of the sides of the bounding box of your outline. 
 
I don't think there's an automatic way to do this, maybe you can find the most external contour approximable with a 4 segment polyline (all doable in opencv). 
 In order to get this you'll have to work with  [contour hierarchy](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) and [contous approximation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) (see `cv2.approxPolyDP`).

 This is how I would go for automatic outline detection.
 As I said, the rest of your algorithm seems just fine to me.

 PS. I'll leave my [Android project GitHub link](https://github.com/magicleon94/Sudoku_scanner/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/magicleon/sudokuscanner). I don't know if it can be useful to you, but here I specify the outline by dragging some handles, then transform the image and feed it to Tesseract, using Java and OpenCV. Yeah It's a very bad idea to do that in the main thread of an Android app and yeah, the app is not finished. I just wanted to experiment with OCR, so I didn't care much of performance and usability, since this was not intended to use, but just for studying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer magicleon! I would have thought that there would be some way to discover that the document orientation by looking at the letter orientation.

Comment: You're welcome man! If I solved your problem/doubt you can mark it as solution ;)

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised considering that this is such a common requirement, that no one hasn't created a library that does all this automatically.

Comment: Maybe someone has. I've never thought of that because I wanted to have a custom experience with the handles, that's all. Maybe there is and I don't know that. If you find anything that does that automatically it would be great (and if you share it here would be great too ;) ), I've just shared my personal experience about the topic :)

Comment: @user3259383 Do you really think that nobody worked on this? Have you googled for "text detection"? OpenCV has it's own [text detection module](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d61/group__text.html)

Comment: I think we were talking about the automatic outline detection

Answer (score 1):

Look up the uniform width transform.

What this does is detect edges which have more or less the same width with respect to their opposite edge. So things like drainpipes (which can be eliminated at a later pass) but also the majority of text. Whilst conceptually it's similar to a distance transform, the published method uses rather ad hoc normal projection methods and Canny edge detection.

Comment: I think you mean **Stroke** width transform